# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar la version de pip correctamente?

Tags: python, pip

Estoy iniciando un proyecto en Python sobre una aplicación para descargar videos y música. Al intentar importar la librería pytube me sale error.
Lo que hice fue abrir la terminal de visual studio code, puse `pip install pytube` y esto fue lo que me salió:

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 22.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Por lo que entiendo tengo que escribir ese comando en el símbolo de sistema para actualizar la versión de pip, pero al intentar me seguía dando error, aunque puede ser que no esté escribiendo lo que me pide como debe ser.

Algunos datos que pueden ser útiles: tengo versión de Python 3.8; en algún momento bajé el editor Jupyter, no sé si influye en algo pero lo agrego también por las dudas.

Comment: Prueba con `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` tal y como te lo dice el mensaje que pusiste

Comment: Cómo se relaciona esto con Java?

Comment: @Alfabravo estuve probando pero me dice que no encuentra la opcion -m

Comment: @Mateo en complejidad jaja

Comment: Has intentando intalarlo desde la direccion que menciona en el warning `c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: Has agregado Python al PATH de windows?

Comment: @GmrYael me parece que el problema esta en el PATH, porque creo que no lo tengo agregado, ahora voy a revisar

Comment: Si te funciona desde la terminal de Visual Studio no es un problema de `PATH`, de todos modos, ejecuta `pip -V` para ver la versión y la ruta completa... Luego ejecuta `pip check` para comprobar la instalación y con `pip help` accedes a la ayuda. Si esto funciona, lo demás también debería funcionar.

Comment: @FranciscoJavier gracias genio! ahi pruebo

Comment: Entonces, ¿por qué dices que vas a mirar el `PATH`...?

Comment: @FranciscoJavier porque habia modificado el PATH hace unos dias y por ahi era ese el error

Comment: Por favor, no agregues etiquetas no relacionadas a la pregunta con tal de intentar captar más atención. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.